# Where do I owe taxes if I am living in one state, but working in another?

Tags: united-states, withholding

[image]

Hello, I am about to start an internship in a neighboring state. Do I file for withholding in my home state or the state I am working in?

I understand that I would be paying taxes to the working state, but I do not know how withholding works OR (if I have the option) which state to have withholding in.

Comment: Telecomute, or drive across the border?

Comment: The HR department at the company should know.  If they outsource it to another company, **they** will definitely know and *should* do the right thing for you.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21159
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/49500
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/55723

Comment: unanswered but similar https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/62229, seems to be a frequent problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My father-in-law worked in a state he didn't live in for many years.  I believe he payed taxes to both states, but I'm not sure and you'll see why in a moment.

In theory, you have to pay income taxes to both states.
In many cases, there are agreements between the two states to limit the income taxes.  In his case, the limit was that you only had to pay the greater of the two.  If you worked in state 1 and lived in state 2, then you first payed taxes in state 1.  If state 1 had a lower tax rate, then you'd end up paying the difference to state 2.

Comment: This is how it is for me.  I work in NC and pay taxes there.  I live in SC and also have to pay taxes, however they give me a credit for what I already pay in NC.  I still end up paying a small amount to SC after the credit.